# Find group of consecutive dates in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to get the chunks of data where there's consecutive dates from the Pandas DataFrame. My `df` looks like below.

```
      DateAnalyzed           Val
1       2018-03-18      0.470253
2       2018-03-19      0.470253
3       2018-03-20      0.470253
4       2018-09-25      0.467729
5       2018-09-26      0.467729
6       2018-09-27      0.467729
```

In this `df`, I want to get the first 3 rows, do some processing and then get the last 3 rows and do processing on that.

I calculated the difference with 1 lag by applying following code.

```
df['Delta']=(df['DateAnalyzed'] - df['DateAnalyzed'].shift(1))
```

But after then I can't figure out that how to get the groups of consecutive rows without iterating.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems like you need two boolean masks: one to determine the breaks between groups, and one to determine which dates are in a group in the first place.

There's also one tricky part that can be fleshed out by example.  Notice that `df` below contains an added row that doesn't have any consecutive dates before or after it.

```
>>> df
  DateAnalyzed       Val
1   2018-03-18  0.470253
2   2018-03-19  0.470253
3   2018-03-20  0.470253
4   2017-01-20  0.485949  # < watch out for this
5   2018-09-25  0.467729
6   2018-09-26  0.467729
7   2018-09-27  0.467729

>>> df.dtypes
DateAnalyzed    datetime64[ns]
Val                    float64
dtype: object
```

The answer below assumes that you want to ignore `2017-01-20` completely, without processing it.    (See end of answer for a solution if you do want to process this date.)

First:

```
>>> dt = df['DateAnalyzed']
>>> day = pd.Timedelta('1d')
>>> in_block = ((dt - dt.shift(-1)).abs() == day) | (dt.diff() == day)
>>> in_block
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: DateAnalyzed, dtype: bool
```

Now, `in_block` will tell you which dates are in a "consecutive" block, but it won't tell you to which groups each date belongs.

The next step is to derive the groupings themselves:

```
>>> filt = df.loc[in_block]
>>> breaks = filt['DateAnalyzed'].diff() != day
>>> groups = breaks.cumsum()
>>> groups
1    1
2    1
3    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
Name: DateAnalyzed, dtype: int64
```

Then you can call `df.groupby(groups)` with your operation of choice.

```
>>> for _, frame in filt.groupby(groups):
...     print(frame, end='\n\n')
... 
  DateAnalyzed       Val
1   2018-03-18  0.470253
2   2018-03-19  0.470253
3   2018-03-20  0.470253

  DateAnalyzed       Val
5   2018-09-25  0.467729
6   2018-09-26  0.467729
7   2018-09-27  0.467729
```

To incorporate this back into `df`, assign to it and the isolated dates will be `NaN`:

```
>>> df['groups'] = groups
>>> df
  DateAnalyzed       Val  groups
1   2018-03-18  0.470253     1.0
2   2018-03-19  0.470253     1.0
3   2018-03-20  0.470253     1.0
4   2017-01-20  0.485949     NaN
5   2018-09-25  0.467729     2.0
6   2018-09-26  0.467729     2.0
7   2018-09-27  0.467729     2.0
```

---

If you do want to include the "lone" date, things become a bit more straightforward:

```
dt = df['DateAnalyzed']
day = pd.Timedelta('1d')
breaks = dt.diff() != day
groups = breaks.cumsum()
```

Comment: I come from the future having needed to do this, and found that `(df.Date.diff(-1) == -day) | (df.Date.diff() == day)` is a little bit cleaner. Where `df.Date` was the date column in my case.

Answer (score 9):

There were similar questions after this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957834/count-consecutive-days-python-dataframe/52957941) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146320/pandas-how-to-get-rows-with-consecutive-dates-and-sales-more-than-1000/65146944#65146944), with more specific outputs requirements. Since this one is more general, I would like to contribute here as well.

We can easily assign an unique identifier to consecutive groups with one-line code:

```
df['grp_date'] = df.DateAnalyzed.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
```

Here, every time we see a date with a difference greater than a day, we add a value to that date, otherwise it remains with the previous value so that we end up with a unique identifier per group.

See the output:

```
  DateAnalyzed       Val  grp_date
1   2018-03-18  0.470253         1
2   2018-03-19  0.470253         1
3   2018-03-20  0.470253         1
4   2018-09-25  0.467729         2
5   2018-09-26  0.467729         2
6   2018-09-27  0.467729         2
```

Now, it's easy to `groupby` "grp_date" and do whatever you wanna do with `apply` or `agg`.

---

Examples:

```py
# Sum across consecutive days (or any other method from pandas groupby)
df.groupby('grp_date').sum()

# Get the first value and last value per consecutive days
df.groupby('grp_date').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0, -1]])
# or df.groupby('grp_date').head(n) for first n days

# Perform custom operation across target-columns
df.groupby('grp_date').apply(lambda x: (x['col1'] + x['col2']) / x['Val'].mean())

# Multiple operations for a target-column
df.groupby('grp_date').Val.agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'std'])

# and so on...
```