# count values of groups by consecutive days

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, grouping

i have data with 3 columns: date, id, sales.
my first task is filtering sales above 100. i did it.
second task, grouping id by consecutive days.

| index | date | id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01/01/2018 | 03 | 101 |
| 1 | 01/01/2018 | 07 | 178 |
| 2 | 02/01/2018 | 03 | 120 |
| 3 | 03/01/2018 | 03 | 150 |
| 4 | 05/01/2018 | 07 | 205 |

the result should be:

| index | id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 03 | 3 |
| 1 | 07 | 1 |
| 2 | 07 | 1 |

i need to do this  task without using pandas/dataframe, but right now i can't imagine from which side attack this problem.
just for effort, i tried the suggestion for a solution here [count consecutive days python dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957834/count-consecutive-days-python-dataframe/52957941)
but the ids' not grouped.
here is my code:

```
data = df[df['sales'] >= 100]
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.date
s = data.groupby('id').date.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
new_frame = data.groupby(['id', s]).size().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

it is very importent that the "new_frame" will have "count" column, because after i need to count id by range of those count days in "count" column. e.g. count of id's in range of 0-7 days, 7-12 days etc. but it's not part of my question.
Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close, but need some fine-tuning, as follows:

```
data = df[df['sales'] >= 100]
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], dayfirst=True)

df2 = data.sort_values(['id', 'date'])
s = df2.groupby('id').date.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
new_frame = df2.groupby(['id', s]).size().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='count')
```

**Result:**

```
print(new_frame)

   id  count
0   3      3
1   7      1
2   7      1
```

**Summary of changes:**

1. As your dates are in `dd/mm/yyyy` instead of the default `mm/dd/yyyy`, you have to specify the parameter `dayfirst=True` in `pd.to_datetime()`.  Otherwise, `02/01/2018` will be regarded as `2018-02-01` instead of `2018-01-02` as expected and the day diff with adjacent entries will be around 30 as opposed to 1.
2. We added a sort step to sort by columns `id` and `date` to simplify the later grouping during the creation of the series `s`.
3. In the last `groupby()` the code `reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` should be dropping `level=1` instead.  Since, `level=0` is the `id` fields which we want to keep.
4. In the last `groupby()`, we do an extra `.reset_index(name='count')` to make the Pandas series change back to a dataframe and also name the new column as `count`.

Comment: SeaBean you are a genius, thank you a lot.
may you explain  to me the need for ne(1) function, what the purpose of this function in the line?
thank you

Comment: @paul  [`.ne()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) is the function to test `not equal`, that, is `!=`.   `ne(1)` is to test not equal to 1 for the date difference between 2 consecutive entries.  Since you want a new group when the date difference is more than 1, we use this test so that whenever the condition is True, (ie. date difference > 1), a new group number is generated by the `.cumsum()` function.

Comment: @paul  Note that the solution you based on is checking consecutive day `not equal` to 1 to generate new group (hence new count).  Beware of the possibility of your data that the date difference could be `0`.  In such case, the diff is 0 which is also `ne(1)`.  So, see whether it is what you want.  You can also consider to change it to `gt(1)` for the case strictly > 1.