# Find the start and end date of consecutive days in a column of the same index using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have a data frame `df`:**

```
df =

index  date        hats
A1     01-01-2020  5
A1     02-01-2020  10
A1     03-01-2020  16
A1     04-01-2020  16
A1     21-01-2020  9
A1     22-01-2020  8
A1     23-01-2020  7
A6     20-03-2020  5
A6     21-03-2020  5
A8     30-07-2020  12
```

Here, the first four rows are consecutive days. I want to know the start date and end date of all such consecutive days in the data frame. If there is only one day in a series like wise `A8` index in the `df` then the start date and and end will be same. Moreover, I am also interested in knowing the highest value in `df['hats']` column in the series of consecutive days and return its date in a seperate column `high_hat` along with its date `high_hat_date`. If there are two or more equal high values in a series of consecutive days then write the number of occurrence of high value in a new column `num_hat`, and write the first occurrence date in `high_hat_date`.

**The example output for the above data frame is as follows:**

```
index   start_date    end_date    high_hat    high_hat_date   num_hat
A1      01-01-2020    04-01-2020  16          03-01-2020      2
A1      21-01-2020    23-01-2020  9           21-01-2020      1
A6      20-03-2020    21-03-2020  5           20-03-2020      2
A8      30-07-2020    30-07-2020  12          30-07-2020      1
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find group of consecutive dates in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901387/find-group-of-consecutive-dates-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @GustavRasmussen Nope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) convert the `date` column to pandas `datetime` series:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
```

**Then use:**

```
g = df.groupby('index')['date'].diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum() # STEP A
m = df.groupby(['index', g])['hats'].transform('max').eq(df['hats']) # STEP B

df = df.assign(high_hats=df['hats'].mask(~m), high_date=df['date'].mask(~m)) # STEP C

dct = {'start_date': ('date', 'first'), 'end_date': ('date', 'last'), 'high_hat': ('hats', 'max'),
       'high_hat_date': ('high_date', 'first'), 'num_hats': ('high_hats', 'count')}
df1 = df.groupby(['index', g]).agg(**dct).reset_index().drop('date', 1) # STEP D
```

**Details:**

STEP A: Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `index` and use [`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) on `date` to calculate the the days elapsed between successive dates then use [`Series.dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) + [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) along with [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to create a grouping series `g` which will be needed to group the dataframe on consecutive dates.

```
# print(g)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
8    3
9    4
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

STEP B: Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `index` and `g` and use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) to transform the column `hats` using `max` then using [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) equate it with `hats` column to create a boolean mask `m`.

```
# print(m)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: hats, dtype: bool
```

STEP C: Next use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to assign two new columns `high_hats` and `high_date` which will be used in `STEP D` for calculation of `high_hat_date` and `num_hats`.

```
# print(df)    
  index       date  hats  high_hats  high_date
0    A1 2020-01-01     5        NaN        NaT
1    A1 2020-01-02    10        NaN        NaT
2    A1 2020-01-03    16       16.0 2020-01-03
3    A1 2020-01-04    16       16.0 2020-01-04
4    A1 2020-01-21     9        9.0 2020-01-21
5    A1 2020-01-22     8        NaN        NaT
6    A1 2020-01-23     7        NaN        NaT
7    A6 2020-03-20     5        5.0 2020-03-20
8    A6 2020-03-21     5        5.0 2020-03-21
9    A8 2020-07-30    12       12.0 2020-07-30
```

STEP D: Using [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `index` and `g` and aggregate the dataframe using the aggregation dictionary `dct` which contains all the columns and their corresponding `agg` functions to be applied.

```
# print(df1)
  index start_date   end_date  high_hat high_hat_date  num_hats
0    A1 2020-01-01 2020-01-04        16    2020-01-03         2
1    A1 2020-01-21 2020-01-23         9    2020-01-21         1
2    A6 2020-03-20 2020-03-21         5    2020-03-20         2
3    A8 2020-07-30 2020-07-30        12    2020-07-30         1
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma great code and guide, particularly going to the lengths to hyperlink to the documentation. This would be a good problem and answer for people to study. I need to study this myself :)

Comment: Thanks @DavidErickson yes its a good conceptual problem.

Answer (score 2):

This required a lot of data transformation:

1. use `np.where()`, `.shift` and `.groupby` + `.transform` to create some intermediary columns to calculate the data ranges of the groups.
2. Create an intermediary dataframe `df2` to calculate some more metrics including `high_hat_date` and `num_hat`. These calculations require a focus on the max values (i.e. high hat), so it was easier to create this new dataframe this way.
3. Merge df2 back into df1, take only the required columns and drop duplicate rows

code:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df1=df.copy()
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], dayfirst=True)
df1['date_diff'] = df1['date'] - df1.shift()['date']
df1['date_first'] = ''
df1['date_first'] = np.where((df1['date_diff'].isnull()) |
                             ((df1['date_diff'] != '1 days') & (df1.shift()['date_diff'] == '1 days')),
                              'start_date', df1['date_first'])
df1['date_first'] = np.where((df1['date_diff'] == '1 days') & (df1.shift(-1)['date_diff'] != '1 days'),
                             'end_date', df1['date_first'])
df1['date_group'] = df1.groupby(df1['date_first'])['date_first'].transform('cumcount')
df1['date_group2'] = df1.groupby(df1['date_first'])['date_group'].transform('cumsum').replace(0,np.nan).ffill().astype(int)
df1['start_date'] = df1.groupby('date_group2')['date'].transform('min')
df1['end_date'] = df1.groupby('date_group2')['date'].transform('max')
df1['high_hat'] = df1.groupby(df1['date_group2'])['hats'].transform('max')
df2 = df1.loc[df1['high_hat'] == df1['hats']]
df2['high_hat_date'] = df2.groupby('date_group2')['date'].transform('first')
df2['num_hat'] = df2.groupby('date_group2')['hats'].transform('count')
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset='date_group2')
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['date_group2', 'high_hat_date', 'num_hat']], how='outer', on=['date_group2'])
df1 = df1[['index', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'high_hat', 'high_hat_date', 'num_hat']].drop_duplicates()
df1
```

output:

```
    index   start_date  end_date    high_hat    high_hat_date   num_hat
0   A1      2020-01-01  2020-01-04  16          2020-01-03      2
4   A1      2020-01-21  2020-01-23  9           2020-01-21      1
7   A6      2020-03-20  2020-03-21  5           2020-03-20      2
9   A8      2020-07-30  2020-07-30  12         2020-07-30       1
```

Comment: @ganesh not as concise as Shubham's code, but this also gets the job done!

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I highly appreciate your work.